# Wordpress Plugin - Why is WP altering "[i]" (and others)?

Tags: wordpress

First off, I'll say that I do have a lot of experience programming, but I'm incredibly inexperienced with WordPress.  I'm guessing there's a correct WordPress way to do what I want and maybe I'm not using the right method, which is why I'm having trouble.

In a nutshell, my plugin reaches out to my company's server via CURL and retrieves a bunch of code (html, css, and javascript) to put on the page.  It's been working fine for many years, but recently our customers have started to complain about broken functionality.  Turns out it's javascript errors.

Digging deeper, we discovered that wordpress (or something) is replacing seemingly arbitrary bracketed text with seemingly arbitrary content.  I see no rhyme or reason to this.  For example, within the following javascript that my plugin pulled in from our server, it replaced the `[i]` with some random html.

Original code:

```js
var optname = order_other_options[oname][i][optid];
```

After wordpress munged it:

```js
var optname = order_other_options[oname]<div class='iconfa' style='text-align: left;'><iclass=''></i></div>[optid];
```

It replaced `[i]` with `<div class='iconfa' style='text-align: left;'><iclass=''></i></div>`

What's weird is that there are probably a dozen instances of `[i]` throughout the same javascript function, but it was only replacing four instance.  ???

For another customer, it's replacing an instance of `[n]` with `&#091;n&#093;`, yet it doesn't try to replace the brackets with &# codes in other instances within that js function.

As a temporary solution for the first customer complaint, we changed the code on our server to be `[x]` instead of `[i]` and that fixed the problem.  But now I see that it seems somewhat indiscriminate about what it replaces.

I could probably write something that prepends js array variables with `ersVar_` or something, something like "[ersVar_x]", but that's such a hack, I'd much rather get to the bottom of the problem.

The way my plugin works is by using `add_filter()`, and our customers utilize the plugin by adding a merge field `[store: <account ID>]`, the plugin then just str-replaces that merge field with our content.

Maybe `add_filter()` isn't the best option?  Is there another function I can use instead that would guarantee that nothing would ever attempt to modify the content my plugin generates?

And if you do recognize what's happening here, I'd be really curious to know, since none of the developers at my office could find any discernible pattern about when and why it replaces things.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Can you please specify what hook you are calling in `apply_filter` and whether or not you are processing/sanitizing the data from response to ensure url safe content? From the looks of it, you are probably using `the_content` hook and some other plugin or code is generating similar shortcodes/replacement parameters. Having a default prefix is always a good idea.

Comment: Yes, "the_content" is what we use.  We're processing the data pretty heavily.  I have a debug panel that I can activate, it includes a base64 encoded version of all the content received (to ensure nothing messes with it), and it looks perfect, nothing is munged, this confirms that all munging is happening later, outside of the plugin.  According to the customer, they tried disabling all plugins and still had the problem, but honestly I don't believe them.  I agree, it seems like a plugin or theme issue.  I wasn't sure if WP itself started doing something like this, but I had my doubts.

Comment: Try changing the priority to a very high value. The data is getting muddled because after processing `the content`, you leave things like `[i]` and `[n]` which is then processed with `do_shortcode`, `wp_kses` and other filters.

Comment: Thank you.  10 is the highest priority you can go, right?  It's currently at 10, but if I can go higher, I'd like to max it out, maybe 100?  I don't want to accidentally use an integer that's too high and ends up being ignored (not sure how WP handles it if the value is over the threshold).

Comment: No, you can go ahead and use **999** as priority. But please be aware that this will move your code execution to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Oh that's great, I didn't know you could go that high.  Thank you, I'll give that a try and see what happens!

Comment: Good Luck mate...

Comment: Faham, I just wanted to let you know, I heard back from one of our customers and he says that solved the problem!  Thank you so much, you're awesome!!

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked and thank you for your kind words. I am adding the details of our conversation as an answer to help anyone else facing a similar problem.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted when and if you would like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was the **hook** and the **priority** used on that hook.

To understand things better, please see the below explanation of the parameters in `add_filter`

1. `Hook`: This is the event that triggers the callback function. In Adam's case the hook was `the_content`.
2. `Callback`: The callback function to be triggered whenever `apply_filters` is called on the respective `hook`.
3. `Priority`: This helps you specify on how early or how late to trigger the callback function. **Defaults to 10**. The lower the number, the earlier the callback is called for execution. *That turned out to be a problem for Adam as by using the default priority of **10**, he was allowing other functions to be called after his has finished execution. It was solved by changing the priority to **999**.*
4. `Parameter Count`: This is the number of parameters accepted by the callback function. **Defaults to 1**.